# Is ESRI Silverlight Mapping API Free or exactly how much (also what about Silverlight Bing Maps)?

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, esri

I am developing a mapping application using ESRI Silverlight API (it's SL map control).  I am not using ArcGIS Server whatsoever.  Once this map application goes commercial (plan for clients to use it - not that many by the way), will I have to pay any pay-per-hit usage or any other related costs?  I know that both the Google Maps API and the Silverlight Bing Maps API cost or correct me if I'm wrong.

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically only free without an ArcGIS Server license for non-commercial use.  Here is a link to the detail:  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/web-mapping/pricing.html

Basically the same goes with Bing maps, free for non-commercial use, and per hits cost with commercial use.  Google maps has a lot more red tape for commercial use.  Bing seems to be more commercial and business friendly with their terms of use where Google seems more consumer focused.

I hope that helps.